# How to take advantage of facebook localisation on static page

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-opengraph

Facebook wants you to use the `og:locale:alternate` meta tag to declare what languages your site is available in.  Unforunetly instead of having a refrence in the tag when they want to use the alternate local they tack `&fb_locale=es_ES` to the end of the URL(or what ever language code they want).  My problem is my site is static so I can't read this extra info easily so was woundering if there was a way in the .htaccess file to remap the url.

so 
`(.*)(?|&)fb_locale=(.*)`    to  `[first 2 letters of $3]/[everything but first 2 letters of $1]`

so

`en/test.html?fb_locale=es_ES`

should go to

`es/test.html`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/(.*)[\?&]fb_locale=([^_]+)_(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%2 [NC,L,R]
```

almost works but for some reason the value after ? still gets appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/([^?&]+)[\?&]fb_locale=([^_]+)_([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%3/%2? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it discards the orignal query strings.

In the last capture group **([^\s]+)** in THE_REQUEST RewriteCond ,we exclude matching spaces \s and tell the regex to match limited chars , because the regex is greedy and it tries to capture  the whole  remaining part of the request string **spaceHTTP/1.1** .

Here is an example of The_Request string :

```
GET /en/index.html?q=foo HTTP/1.1
```

And the correct regex pattern without capture groups to match against it :

```
/en/index\.html\?q=foo
```

Pattern with regex capture groups :

```
/([^/]+)/([^?]+)\?q=([^\s]+)
```

The first capture group captures **/en** , the second captures **/index.html** and the third capture group captures the value of key.

Comment: thanks so much.  To make this even more precise I restricted the first capture group to 2 letter.   `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+){2}/(.*)[\?&]fb_locale=([^_]+)_([^\s]+) [NC]` and set the redirect to perminent `RewriteRule ^ /%3/%2? [NC,L,R=301]`

Comment: @matthewCornelisse Your first capture group is still capturing one or more chars excluding /, the correct syntex is **([^/]{2})**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

#if the requested url is /en/test.html?fb_locale=foo_bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/test\.html\?fb_locale=([^_]+)_[^\s]+ [NC]
#Then redirect the request to /es/test.html?fb_locale=foo
RewriteRule ^ /es/test.html?fb_locale=%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: that doesn't work but it did get me thinking.  See the code I added to the bottom of the question.  Almost work but for some reason it keep the ?fb_locale.. causing an infinit loop